# Unequal timing of alternating LEDs in a multivibtrator

Tags: multivibrator

[image]

[image]

I have built a basic astable multivibrator from the *Electronics for Dummies* book.

The LEDs alternate for sure but one lights for a much longer time than the other.

I would have expected this if the capacitors were different but they are not (100uF.) I built it first from the schematic.  When that didn’t work, I literally followed the author’s table of breadboard grid connected but it still has  the same problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "Any thoughts?" Yes, but they're just wild guesses in the dark unless you show the actual schematic used and maybe a photo of the breadboard layout. You can [Edit] them in.

Comment: we cannot see which is connected to what without you posting a schematic with part numbers.

Comment: Assuming it's one of the symmetrical designs you could swap parts from side to side until you find out what is causing it. That's a basic troubleshooting technique.

Comment: Components have tolerances, and some capacitors can be off by as much as 20% or even more. Transistor betas can differ wildly too. You need to put a number on that "much longer".

Comment: `Electronics for Dummies` ... i wonder if there is `ventriloquism for dummies`

Comment: Thanks. Now please see photos. Project a bit messy with jumper wires sorry. By “much longer” I mean that one will flash about 10 - 15 times longer than the other. I have swapped out all components. Rechecked wiring. No good. Am stumped.

Comment: Polarized electrolytic capacitors do have very  wide tolerances. How do you check they are not different?

Comment: Ok! Now, don’t be too critical of me! After all, I said I was new at this!! As it turns out, one of my 10k resistors turned out to be, in fact, a 100k resistor!! Thanks to you all. I assume you will try to avoid my silly questions in future! But don’t write me off!!

Answer (score 2):

The upper "10kΩ" resistor in that photo does not seem to be 10kΩ. I can't see the exact colour of the 4th band, but I don't think it's orange.

Comment: Yes, these resistors look suspiciously similar to the famous aliexpress resistor kit where all the values are wrong...